I don't understand why LayerNorm is killing cosine predictions
I have a very plain cosine prediction model:
batch_size = 20

Conv1D(filters=1, kernel=10, padding="same")
RELU
Dense(1)
Tanh

If I add LayerNormalization between 1 and 2 or between 2 and 3, fails to predict cos during training and inference, outputs the same float for every step.
However LayerNormalization works when 1 and 2 are LSTM or Dense + RELU. Moreso, BatchNormalization layer works for any combination I tried.
What is happening?
